# BizTalk :: The start element with name "X" and namespace "Y" was unexpected

Tags: xml, xsd, biztalk, xsd-validation, biztalk-2013

I came across error message below in BizTalk:

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port
>   "TIMESHEET_ODS_GMPS_FAB" with URL
>   "mssql://SINGVSQLD8/VID08/GMPS?InboundId=CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS".
>   It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this
>   Send Port.
>   Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException:
>   The start element with name "CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS" and
>   namespace
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo/GMPS" was
>   unexpected. Please ensure that your input XML conforms to the schema
>   for the operation.

I understand that there has been several posts with the same topic previously, but unfortunately none apply as I have tried attempts below with no result:

1. Validate Instance between run–time Message and the Schema to ensure
   that input XML conforms to the Schema
2. Ensure that Message being set to correct Message Type throughout
   Orchestration flow
3. Use consistent Namespace
   http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo/GMPS in the
   Schema
4. Use Operation Name "CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS" in SOAP Action
   Header to match with Send Port Operation Identifier and use
   Operation Action "Procedure/dbo/CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS" to
   match with the Namespace

In addition, there are several other things that may or may not be related:

1. I tried to set Root Reference property
2. No schema using same Namespace
3. No Port using same InboundID
4. I’m not using XML Transmit for this particular schema

My run–time [but shortened] Message is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo/GMPS">
  <p_request_xml>&lt;GMPS_FAB&gt;&lt;record&gt;&lt;fromdate&gt;2014-02-01T00:00:00&lt;/fromdate&gt;&lt;todate&gt;2014-02-07T00:00:00&lt;/todate&gt;&lt;empno&gt;00157772&lt;/empno&gt;&lt;legacyempnum&gt;90297&lt;/legacyempnum&gt;&lt;timesheet_date&gt;2014-02-05T00:00:00&lt;/timesheet_date&gt;&lt;paycode&gt;AUST-NOR-SAL&lt;/paycode&gt;&lt;spanid&gt;63295458&lt;/spanid&gt;&lt;contractnum&gt;R3133&lt;/contractnum&gt;&lt;company_code&gt;0244&lt;/company_code&gt;&lt;job_project&gt;45985&lt;/job_project&gt;&lt;subacct_costctr&gt;CRPMT&lt;/subacct_costctr&gt;&lt;ctr_opcode&gt;CR001&lt;/ctr_opcode&gt;&lt;wbs_code /&gt;&lt;ll1worked&gt;0244&lt;/ll1worked&gt;&lt;ll2worked&gt;0100&lt;/ll2worked&gt;&lt;ll3worked&gt;45985&lt;/ll3worked&gt;&lt;ll4worked&gt;CRPMT&lt;/ll4worked&gt;&lt;ll6worked /&gt;&lt;hoursamt&gt;8.000000&lt;/hoursamt&gt;&lt;acttrantype&gt;O&lt;/acttrantype&gt;&lt;billot&gt;R&lt;/billot&gt;&lt;billotrate&gt;119.790000&lt;/billotrate&gt;&lt;diff_rate /&gt;&lt;diff_ot_rate&gt;0.00000000000000&lt;/diff_ot_rate&gt;&lt;direct_ind&gt;D&lt;/direct_ind&gt;&lt;emp_base_rate&gt;119.790000&lt;/emp_base_rate&gt;&lt;emp_ot_rate&gt;0.000000000000&lt;/emp_ot_rate&gt;&lt;interfaceflag /&gt;&lt;vendorcode /&gt;&lt;PAYRULE&gt;AUST-STAFF-EXEC&lt;/PAYRULE&gt;&lt;hourstype&gt;REG&lt;/hourstype&gt;&lt;emp_engage_type&gt;N&lt;/emp_engage_type&gt;&lt;contractor_ot_rate /&gt;&lt;last_modified&gt;2014-02-06T19:27:16.400&lt;/last_modified&gt;&lt;process_date&gt;2014-03-26T22:29:04.417&lt;/process_date&gt;&lt;calendar_id&gt;502&lt;/calendar_id&gt;&lt;equip_depth /&gt;&lt;equip_block /&gt;&lt;equip_loc /&gt;&lt;fullnm&gt;Burry, Raymond W&lt;/fullnm&gt;&lt;shiftcode&gt;8&lt;/shiftcode&gt;&lt;ll1home&gt;0244&lt;/ll1home&gt;&lt;ll2home&gt;5000&lt;/ll2home&gt;&lt;ll3home&gt;52363&lt;/ll3home&gt;&lt;craftcode /&gt;&lt;exportflag /&gt;&lt;job_discipline_code /&gt;&lt;job_discipline_name&gt;Project Engineer (Eng)&lt;/job_discipline_name&gt;&lt;application_code&gt;GMPS&lt;/application_code&gt;&lt;application_name&gt;GMPS&lt;/application_name&gt;&lt;calgroup_name&gt;GMPS APAC Engineering&lt;/calgroup_name&gt;&lt;calgroup_desc&gt;GMPS AP Engineering&lt;/calgroup_desc&gt;&lt;location_code&gt;SING&lt;/location_code&gt;&lt;calendar_name&gt;GMPS_GMPS APAC Engineering_02012014_02072014&lt;/calendar_name&gt;&lt;date_last_extracted&gt;2014-03-24T22:23:00&lt;/date_last_extracted&gt;&lt;/record&gt;&lt;/GMPS_FAB&gt;</p_request_xml>
  <p_response_xml xsi:nil="true" />
</CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS>
```

My Schema is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<xs:schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo/GMPS" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data/GMPS" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo/GMPS" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:import schemaLocation=".\DataSetSchema.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data/GMPS" /> 
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<fileNameHint xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/xsd">Procedure.dbo</fileNameHint> 
<b:references>
<b:reference targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data/GMPS" /> 
</b:references>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:element name="CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
<doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">Procedure/dbo/CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS</doc:action> 
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="p_request_xml" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="p_response_xml" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPSResponse">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
<doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">Procedure/dbo/CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS/response</doc:action> 
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPSResult" nillable="true" type="ns3:ArrayOfDataSet" /> 
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ReturnValue" type="xs:int" /> 
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="p_response_xml" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My SOAP Action Header is as below:

```
<BtsActionMapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Operation Name="CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS" Action="Procedure/dbo/CSP_BT_TIMESHEET_ODS_TO_GMPS" />
</BtsActionMapping>
```

If you have ever experienced similar error message or see that something is wrong with my code, a clue will be much appreciated.

Comment: Any clue at all will be helpful and much appreciated.., as I've been wandering around this error message for several weeks now. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has now been resolved.
I encountered several other issue including timeout issue afterward though until I finally finished the development just now and about to promote to QA.

Long story short, I received an offline suggestion mentioning that I should not modify one schema and just find-and-replace everything to be used as other schema even if I made a clean find-and-replace process.
Therefore I recreated the schema from scratch and redeployed and everything worked well all of the sudden.

In addition, I used http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo namespace instead of the one with /GMPS postfix in the newly created schema as it was the given default.
Aside from the namespace, everything else in the new schema is the exact match [from the way I see it, at least] with the old one.

However, since my project now a little bit behind schedule, I didn't try to:
[1] Only change the namespace without recreating the schema from scratch
[2] To try to use the namespace with /GMPS postfix after recreating the schema from scratch

This post made for future reference purpose only.